Unable to see or access mapped drive from C# Windows Service
I have a C# service that I am unable to modify running on Windows Server. Internally this service has a function that uses DriveInfo.GetDrives to get a list of available drives, returning that information to an API. However while this returns the C drive it fails to detect a drive mapped from another machine created via the following Powershell script:
$cred = Get-Credential -Credential myusername
New-PSDrive -Name "Z" -Root "\\192.168.1.24\SharedFolder" -Persist -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Credential $cred -Scope Global
Net Use
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"

I have tried creating new users with permission to access the drive and getting the service to log on as that user, changing permissions for the mapped drive as well as double checking that the following registry key existed (it did):
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"EnableLinkedConnections"=dword:00000001

I also tried each of the following to get the service running under different system accounts:
sc config ServiceName obj= "NT AUTHORITY\Local Service" password= ""

sc config ServiceName obj= "NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" password= ""

However nothing works. I created a simple C# application that uses DriveInfo.GetDrives and it returns both the C drive as well as the mapped Z drive. This is clearly some sort of permissions issue. What am I missing? Any help very much appreciated.

What happens if you use file explorer to access the folder with same URL?

I can access \192.168.1.24\SharedFolder via Explorer but not Z:\

The z: has to be in the same powershell session : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-7.4

You need to run the script under the user which the service uses.
The service may not monitor the drives and uses drives available during startup. In this case, you need to start the service with a delay and run the script prior the service started. It can be done by another dedicated service which you should create. Or maybe you can use the system scheduler to run the script on system startup. Another way is to restart the service after the new drive mapped.
So first include the service restart command in your script and run the script under service's user account.
